# Is it true that if $E(X)=0$, then $E(X\mid\mathcal{G})=0$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $\mathcal{G}\subset \mathcal{F}$ is a sub sigma-algebra and $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable r.v. such that $E(X)=0$. Is it correct that $E(X\mid\mathcal{G})=0$? I know the converse is true.

Comment: not always true. You can have a non-zero $X$ that is measurable w.r.t $\mathcal{G},$ in which case $E(X|\mathcal{G}) = X\neq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer and comment above use counter-examples where $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

For the sake of argument, let's do an example where $X$ is not $\mathcal{G}$-measurable (in particular, $\mathcal{F} \neq \mathcal{G}$).

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$, $\mathcal{F}$ be the power set of $\Omega$, and $\mathcal{G} = \{\phi, \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \Omega\}$.  Put the uniform measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, that is, $\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac{1}{4} (\# A)$.

Define $X$ by $X(1) = -2$, $X(2) = -1$, $X(3) = 1$, and $X(4) = 2$.  A computation shows that $\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$.  On the other hand, $Y = \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})$ is given by $Y(1) = Y(2) = -\frac{3}{2}$ and $Y(3) = Y(4) = \frac{3}{2}$.  In particular, $Y$ is non-constant, even though $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(X) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $\Omega$ be some finite set, $\mathcal F = \mathcal G=2^\Omega,$ and $X$ be some nonconstant random variable with expectation zero.